# How to automatically expand a type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I plan to pass Entity-class descendant objects to a function and call a unique implementation of the same function, but I can't figure out how to do it without strong typing. I want to have different behavior for each type of inheritor.

```
public IRepository<Entity> choose(Entity entity) 
{
    return _repositories.FirstOrDefault(h => h.GetType().Namespace == entity.getStorePlace(((WeatherEntity)entity).getRealStorePlace)); 
}


public class Entity : IEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string getStorePlace(Func<string> f)
    {
        return f();
    }
}


public class WeatherEntity : Entity, IweatherEntity
{
        public string name { get; set; } = null!;
        public int temperature { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; } = null!;
        public bool isRainyToday { get; set; } = false;
       
        public  string  getRealStorePlace()
        {
                if (temperature > 25)
                {
                        return "ConsoleAppTest.Repositories.MongoRepositories";

                }
                return "ConsoleAppTest.Repositories.JsonRepositories";
        }
}
```

I tried to add unique function to the Entity class and override it in WeatherEntity Class, but got the same result.

Comment: How can you have a "unique implementation of the same function"?

Comment: I tried to override it

Comment: Can you try to explain what it is you're really trying to do here? Having types as strings is a real code smell.

Comment: You can't override as it has a different signature.

Comment: I want to use different heirs of Entity class in choose() function to get the place, where i can store that object. I want to use a getRealStorePlace to define conditions to each type of Entity heirs.

Comment: No, I mean, can you go to the next level of abstraction? What you are trying to do here is a bad code smell. I'd like to understand the problem you think you're solving by doing this, not what you're asking in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Entity class to abstracted and it workes now.

```
 public IRepository<Entity> choose(Entity entity) 
    {
        return _repositories.FirstOrDefault(h => h.GetType().Namespace == entity.getStorePlace(entity.getRealStorePlace)); 
    }

public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string getStorePlace(Func<string> f)
    {
        return f();
    }

    public abstract string getRealStorePlace();
}


public class WeatherEntity : Entity, IweatherEntity
{
        
     
        public string name { get; set; } = null!;

        public int temperature { get; set; }

        public string location { get; set; } = null!;

        public bool isRainyToday { get; set; } = false;
       
          public override string  getRealStorePlace()
        {
                if (temperature > 25)
                {
                        return "ConsoleAppTest.Repositories.MongoRepositories";

                }
                return "ConsoleAppTest.Repositories.JsonRepositories";
        }

}
```

Comment: You still should replace the return type to a Type instead of a string and why the indirection via getStorePlace just call getRealStorePlace.

Comment: The `getStorePlace()` in this case doesn't make sense. Instead of getting namespaces, it simply executes a `string` function and returns the result. That means I can write a `FunnyEntity` and returns hardcoded `"Apple"` in `FunnyEntity.getRealStorePlace()`, and it'd still work. You should figure out the correct implementation about that too, but for now, the condition should be sufficient with `h.GetType().Namespace == entity.getRealStorePlace()`, i.e. `Entity.getStorePlace()` is not necessary in your usecase.